# How to read value from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm sorry for the specificity of this situation, but I just can't wrap my head around the issue.

I've created the following JSON file:

```
{"characters":[
{"name":"battler", "sprites": 
    [{"img":"but_a11_aseru1.png","img":"but_a11_komaru1.png","img":"but_a21_majime1.png","img":"but_b11_majime1.png"}]
},
{"name":"eva", "sprites": 
    [{"img":"eva_a11_akire1.png","img":"eva_b11_majime1.png","img":"eva_b21_naku1.png","img":"eva_b22_warai1.png"}]
}
]}
```

And I am attempting to load it with this code, just to echo the value for "img" for the first "sprites" in each entry for now:

```
$.getJSON( "./char.json", function( data ) {
            for (i = 0;i < data.characters.length;i++) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data.characters[i].sprites[0]));
    }
});
```

For example: I'm trying to get it to return "but_a11_aseru1.png" for the first iteration of the loop and "eva_a11_akire1.png" for the second.

I've tried `data.characters[i].sprites[0]`, only to get a value of `{"img":"but_a11_aseru1.png"}` for the first (and similar for the second). `data.characters[i].sprites.img` turns up as undefined.  I could use .split at the ":" but I want to understand how to properly use JSON.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get expected output ("but_a11_aseru1.png" for the first iteration) with your code, you need to make `sprites` an array with items corresponding to individual images:

```
{"characters":[
  {"name":"battler", "sprites": [
    "but_a11_aseru1.png",
    "but_a11_komaru1.png",
    "but_a21_majime1.png",
    "but_b11_majime1.png"
  ]},
  {"name":"eva", "sprites": [
    "eva_a11_akire1.png",
    "eva_b11_majime1.png",
    "eva_b21_naku1.png",
    "eva_b22_warai1.png"
  ]}
]}
```

and

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.characters[i].sprites[0]));
```

or

```
{"characters":[
  {"name":"battler", "sprites": [
    {"img":"but_a11_aseru1.png"},
    {"img":"but_a11_komaru1.png"}, 
    {"img":"but_a21_majime1.png"},
    {"img":"but_b11_majime1.png"}
  ]},
  {"name":"eva", "sprites": [
    {"img":"eva_a11_akire1.png"},
    {"img":"eva_b11_majime1.png"},
    {"img":"eva_b21_naku1.png"},
    {"img":"eva_b22_warai1.png"}
  ]}
]}
```

and

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.characters[i].sprites[0].img));
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much! I thought to try something similar, but evidently I completely failed at syntaxing it correctly, so I just assumed it was wrong. You've saved me a lot of time, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your original JSON isn't well formed. You declare "sprites" to be an array, but then all of the `img` keys belong to a *single* object. Fixed this by making sprites an array of objects instead of an array of a single badly-formed object.

```
{
  "characters": [{
    "name": "battler",
    "sprites": [{
      "img": "but_a11_aseru1.png",
      "img": "but_a11_komaru1.png",
      "img": "but_a21_majime1.png",
      "img": "but_b11_majime1.png"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "eva",
    "sprites": [{
      "img": "eva_a11_akire1.png",
      "img": "eva_b11_majime1.png",
      "img": "eva_b21_naku1.png",
      "img": "eva_b22_warai1.png"
    }]
  }]
}
```

The below code works for me. I used jQuery's `$.each()` function, but you could have realistically used anything you wanted to loop through the items.

```js
var json_data = {
  "characters": [{
    "name": "battler",
    "sprites": [{
      "img": "but_a11_aseru1.png"
    }, {
      "img": "but_a11_komaru1.png"
    }, {
      "img": "but_a21_majime1.png"
    }, {
      "img": "but_b11_majime1.png"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "eva",
    "sprites": [{
      "img": "eva_a11_akire1.png"
    }, {
      "img": "eva_b11_majime1.png"
    }, {
      "img": "eva_b21_naku1.png"
    }, {
      "img": "eva_b22_warai1.png"
    }]
  }]
};

$.each(json_data.characters, function(i, character) {
  console.log(character.name, " ", character.sprites[0].img);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different structure for the sprites, currently you have an array with one object with several keys img which are the same, Browsers will only show the last one, the rest will be omitted.

```js
var data = {
  "characters": [
    {
      "name":"battler",
      "sprites": [
        {"img":"but_a11_aseru1.png"},
        {"img":"but_a11_komaru1.png"},
        {"img":"but_a21_majime1.png"},
        {"img":"but_b11_majime1.png"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"eva",
      "sprites": [
        {"img":"eva_a11_akire1.png"},
        {"img":"eva_b11_majime1.png"},
        {"img":"eva_b21_naku1.png"},
        {"img":"eva_b22_warai1.png"}
      ]
    }
  ]
};

$.each(data.characters, function(i, char) {
  $.each(char.sprites, function(j, sprite) {
    console.log(sprite.img)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```